# Using a vector of column names in mutate_at

Tags: r, dplyr

This is my data:

```
ID a b c d
1  x 1 2 3
2  y 1 2 3
3  z NA NA NA
4  z 1 2 3
5  y NA NA NA
```

Now, if I wanted to replace the NAs in a single column, say b, with the mean of b by the group a, I know how to do it by using this code:

```
data %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate(b = ifelse(is.na(b), as.integer(mean(b, na.rm=TRUE)), b)
```

I want to use basically the same code but to apply it over columns b,c,d. But the code I have isn't working and I don't know why, it says "error, incompatible size (3), expecting 10 (the group size) or 1"

```
cols <- c("b","c","d")
data %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate_at(.cols = cols, funs(ifelse(is.na(cols), 
    as.integer(mean(cols, na.rm=TRUE)), cols)
```

I'm assuming the problem has to do with the code not correctly applying the column names when looking at the data?

Comment: You need to use `.` within `funs` to represent the data, not the vector of names, e.g. `df %>%
    group_by(a) %>%
    mutate_at(cols, funs(ifelse(is.na(.), as.integer(mean(., na.rm=TRUE)), .)))`

Comment: So, if I wanted just the columns b,c,d then I should write .(cols)? Because when I try that it says "Cannot find function "b"" 
It thinks that the first value in cols b, is a function, for some reason...

Comment: No. `.` stands in for the variable in the function you build in `funs`, not a function itself. `cols` goes to the first parameter of `mutate_at`, but doesn't go in the second, because that needs to be a function that operates on each variable (`.`) independently. Passing in `cols` into `funs` will pass in a vector of strings, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 5):

for referencing a character vector to mutate use **mutate_if** instead.

```
cols <- c("b","c","d")

data %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate_if(names(.) %in% cols, 
            funs(ifelse(is.na(.), as.integer(mean(., na.rm=TRUE)), .)))
```